# How to turn off pop-up box in VBA Excel on Macbook

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Whenever I typed any text on VBA Excel, the pop-up box automatically appears as the photo. Do you know how to turn it off?
I am using Office 2019 for Mac.

[image]

I tried to turn off some options in Tools -> references and Excel -> Reference but it does not work.

Comment: if excel for mac has Tools->Options->Editor then *maybe* what you are looking for is to uncheck "Auto list members" (or perhaps another option) on that tab.

Comment: I've never seen anything like that. Are you sure there are no plugins/add-ins installed in Excel?

Comment: hi @Stax thanks for your suggestion, I tried but it doesn't work ...

Comment: hi @Pᴇʜ yes, I tried to turn off all add-ins but the problem still remains